# How to use LIKE with ORDER BY CASE for partial text search in WHEN statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-order-by

How do you use LIKE with ORDER BY CASE in SQL? Or in other words, how do you do a partial text search for the following:

ORDER BY CASE [Column Name] WHEN [value partial text%]

Problem: I'm referencing a table (named "Personnel") with column (titled "Rank"), which lists each employee's job title followed by their level of certification (many variables). I would like to order the SQL query results by job title, ignoring the certification level that follows title name.

Example values in Personnel.Rank Column:
Captain Paramedic
Captain Intermediate
Captain EMT
Lieutenant Paramedic
Lieutenant Intermediate
Lieutenant EMT
Apparatus Operator Paramedic
Firefighter EMT
Firefighter AEMT

This works, but I don't want to list every variable as a WHEN clause:

```
SELECT 
p.Rank
FROM Personnel p
ORDER BY 
    CASE p.Rank
    WHEN 'Captain Paramedic' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Captain EMT' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Lieutenant Paramedic' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Lieutenant EMT' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
```

I would like to know how to do something like this instead:

```
SELECT 
p.Rank
FROM Personnel p
ORDER BY 
    CASE p.Rank
    WHEN LIKE 'Captain%' THEN 1
    WHEN LIKE 'Lieutenant%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
```

Thoughts?

LIKE operator is not permitted with ORDER BY CASE [column name] WHEN statement

Comment: which database system are you using, your ocde is not valid

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (post was tagged with SQL)

Comment: then see the answer, it is vital to tag the correct database, as all are different in behaviour

Comment: Agreed - and it was originally tagged.

Comment: no, the hostiry was no tag for `sql server` which is a separate tag as you can check now

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you can just fix up the syntax and still use your case statement. Untested but the syntax I would expect is:

```
SELECT 
p.Rank
FROM Personnel p
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN p.Rank LIKE 'Captain%' THEN 1
    WHEN p.Rank LIKE 'Lieutenant%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
    END
```

A more general purpose solution would be to use a reference or lookup table to get your order by values. Here is an example written in PSEUDOSQL just to show the idea. In real life, you can create your table or use a temp table or a CTE. The pro here is you can maintain this a little more cleanly (in your ref table - or SortOrder can be a field right in your Personnel table). The con here is you have "promoted" a simple ordering problem into something more permanent and if this is only an ad hoc need for an ad hoc query then it might be overkill.

```
create temporary table SortOrder (Rank, SortOrder)

insert into SortOrder
values
    ('Captain Paramedic', 10),
    ('Captain Intermediate', 10),
    ('Captain EMT', 10),
    ('Lieutenant Paramedic', 20),
    ('Lieutenant Intermediate', 20),
    ('Lieutenant EMT', 20),
    ('Apparatus Operator Paramedic', 30),
    ('Firefighter EMT', 40),
    ('Firefighter AEMT', 40)

SELECT 
    p.Rank
FROM 
    Personnel p
    LEFT JOIN SortOrder s
    ON p.Rank = s.Rank
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(s.SortOrder, 100)
```